# Binding object to directive's bindToController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive

```
.directive('showMessage',[function(){
    return{
        scope:true,
        restrict:'E',
        bindToController:{
            sprop:"="
        },
        templateUrl:'Communicator/Views/showMessage.html',
        controllerAs:"showMessCtrl",
        controller:function($scope){
            console.log(this.sprop);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I am trying to pass a object to the directive into sprop like this

```
//base controller  
        $scope.mySplitterProp ={
            orientation:"vertical",
            collapsible:false,
            max:"75%"
        }
```

The calling of directive is like this

```
<show-message sprop="{{mySplitterProp}}"></show-message>
```

If i use sprop:"@", this return a string in the console.log (i need object)
and if i use sprop:"=" (which is supposed to be used), i get a error like

> [$parse:syntax]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7BmySplitterProp%7D%7D&p4=%7BmySplitterProp%7D%7D

I am using angular 1.4

Comment: sprop="mySplitterProp" instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{mySplitterProp}} will replace the variable by the value, and, will not pass it to the directive scope when using two-way binding '=' (because it expect the expression to change ...). Remove the curly braces.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: woo , magic .. Why does the binding work when using '@' but not when using '='

Comment: Because in one-way binding "@" value will not change, but, in the two-way binding the value change (=> variable) so, you should provide reference to object not its value ...